# Angular 5 : View not updating

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

In my view i'm rendering a list of skills, using an observable and *ngFor

I retrieve the skills with the following code:

```
getSkills(): void {
    this.skillsDataService.getSkills()
        .subscribe(
            skills => this.skills = skills.sort( this.skillSort )
        );
}
```

However i've learned that it's better to use named functions and not too much nesting. So i changed the code to this:

```
getSkills(): void {
    this.skillsDataService.getSkills()
        .subscribe(
            this.processSkills
        );
}

processSkills(skills: Skill[]): void {
    this.skills = skills.sort( this.skillSort );
}
```

And now the view doesn't update, eventhough this.skills is filled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "this" in processSkills will not be the controller when you call it like that. In order to understand what i mean you should just log out "this" inside of processSkills and take a course on how "this" works in JavaScript.
In order to make your code work, try this instead:

```
.subscribe(
        this.processSkills.bind(this)
    );
```

Comment: Omg, i you're right. i should've know.. New to typescript, well know with javascript. Thnx! (will accept your answer once allowed by stackoverflow)